# Workflow State not changing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation, state

i m trying to change the state for workflow from one state to another on button click its working fine with windows but not with web application and its instance id does not persist i have used SqlWorkflowPersistenceService also.
what can b the solution for this.

thanks

Comment: Workflow version 3 or 4?

Comment: i m using visual studio 2008 framework 3.5

Comment: Where is WF hosted in your system?

Comment: currently i m trying on desktop but i have to implemente on network

Comment: i m using state workflow as dll in my asp.net application

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...a little more detail would be useful...unfortunately my reputation does not allow me to comment yet, so I will post advice as an answer:

If your persistence service is not working on the web application then I would strongly suggest that this is a database connectivity issue.

What is the connection string that you're using for the persistence service?
What are the security settings on the web application?
Which user does the application pool run as?

Check the logs on the SQL Server - are there any errors there regarding login failures etc?

As you're hosting the WF Runtime under IIS then it's definitely worth making sure of these things.